# Combine JsonDeserialize#contentAs with JsonDeserialize#contentConverter or JsonDeserialize#contentUsing for custom deserialization

Tags: jackson, json-deserialization

In [JsonDeserialize](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonDeserialize.html) annotation documentation the contentAs field is supposed to define the "*Concrete type to deserialize content*".

I tried to use this in combination, with either a Converter (via contentConverter field of the same annotation) or a JsonDeserializer (via contentUsing field of the same annotation), by extending either StdConverter or StdDeserializer, respectively, in an attempt to create an agnostic custom deserializer. 
I cannot find a way to access the JsonDeserialize#contentAs information inside any of these two classes.

I am aware that the classes I extend from have a type parameter, I just put an Object class there. Documentation states

> contentAs Concrete type to deserialize content (elements of a Collection/array, values of Maps) values as, instead of type otherwise declared. Must be a subtype of declared type; otherwise an exception may be thrown by deserializer.

Apparently I am applying the @JsonDeserializer annotation on a Collection of some persistable Class. I want to deserialize each such object, solely by knowing its id. Well, if I could only get that very type I defined in the @JsonDeserializer#contentAs field...

Can anyone tell me if this is possible anyhow?

Comment: I think you should try to explain WHAT you are trying to achieve, instead of explaing HOW you are trying to achieve that. This way it would be easier to try to help find a way to get the results: your current approach may not be a good way to get there. In this case, explaining Java classes of values you are trying to deserialize (as properties of a POJO) would help a lot.

Comment: @StaxMan "*I tried to use this in combination, ... , in an attempt to create an agnostic custom deserializer.*" 
and later on:
"*I want to deserialize each such object, solely by knowing its id.*"
(I can track the id by means of reflection). I think that covers the "*WHAT*" part

Comment: I am not sure "agnostic custom deserializer" is clear without explaining it further: I could guess what it might mean from further discussion, but not initially. Anyway, looks like you were able to solve the problem with a reasonable way so I guess it's a moot point now.

Comment: I admit the content was a bit "dense". I tried to avoid a lengthy post that might be treated with "tldr" by readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to implement the agnostic deserializer withou the use of *@JsonDeserializer#contentAs* after all.

After reading the javadocs of *com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer* I concluded that my custom deserializer should implement the *com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ContextualDeserializer* interface.

Inside the implementation of *ContextualDeserializer#createContextual(DeserializationContext ctxt, BeanProperty property)*
I could finally get access to the class type of the content of the collection, which I applied the @JsonDeserialize annotation on,
by calling:

```
ctxt.getContextualType().getRawClass()
```

**NOTE** that the same call inside the implementation of *com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer#deserialize(com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser, com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext)* returned null, hence the need of the aforementioned interface.

<s>All I had to do then is store the returned class in a member field (of type Class< ? >) of the custom deserializer and use it in the execution of *JsonDeserializer#deserialize()*</s>

The only thing that remains to check is whether an instance of this custom deserializer is shared between threads. I only did some minor checks; I used the same implementation for two different collections of different types. I observed that *ContextualDeserializer#createContextual(DeserializationContext ctxt, BeanProperty property)* was called once (among multiple deserialization invokations), for each distinct type that was going to be deserialized. After checking during debugging, it seems that the same deserializer object is used for the same type. In my case, since what I store in the member field is this type itself, I don't mind if the same deserializer is used for the *same* java type to be deserialized because they ***should*** contain the same value. So we 're clear on this aspect as well.

EDIT: It appears all I have to do is update the *com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer#_valueClass* value to the now known class. Since it is final and since the *ContextualDeserializer#createContextual(DeserializationContext ctxt, BeanProperty property)* returns a JsonSerializer object, which is actually used, 
instead of returning "*this*" serializer I can create a new one, passing the discovered class in the constructor, which actually sets the *StdDeserializer#_valueClass* to the class I actually want, and I'm all set!

Finally, **NOTE** that I didn't have to use the *@JsonDeserializer#contentAs* annotationfield as I get the value from the *ctxt.getContextualType().getRawClass()* statement inside *ContextualDeserializer#createContextual(DeserializationContext ctxt, BeanProperty property)* implementation

Comment: Yes, `getContextualType()` is only available during construction of a (de)serializer since setting it throughout actual (de)serialization is costly and unnecessary for most use cases and most of the time (as constructed (de)serializers are cached). Also, yes, you should be creating a new deserializer instance (like you are doing) because otherwise there would be thread-safety issues: deserializers are expected to be stateless. So I think you found a reasonable solution to your problem.

Comment: @StaxMan although I managed to do my job as described above, I'm still wondering how I could access the _@JsonDeserializer#contentAs_ value after all...

Comment: You can access that information from `createContextual()` method of `ContextualDeserializer`: `BeanProperty` should both have type after modifications (something like getType()), and allow you to, if you really want to, call `AnnotationIntrospector` (available via `DeserializationContext` argument) to look for actual values of annotation. But preferably `BeanProperty` has info you need (also note: for root-level deserializer it'd be `null` as there's no referring property).